# XSLT group and sum

Tags: xslt

I need to generate a HTML table based off some XML that looks like the following:

```
<file>
    <name>data.js</name>
    <dir>/ui/view</dir>
    <errors>5</errors>
</file>
<file>
    <name>main.js</name>
    <dir>/ui/view</dir>
    <errors>6</errors>
</file>
<file>
    <name>redirect.js</name>
    <dir>/tools/network</dir>
    <errors>1</errors>
</file>
```

It needs to look at the content of the dir element and group them by the first directory of the path.  Based off those groupings, the errors need to be summed.

The table would look something like the following given the example data.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ui</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tools</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've looked at a lot of the questions and see how something similar can be done if an attribute or element could be grouped as is.  However, the twist with this is that the dir needs to be parsed and grouped by the root directory.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: This is an addition to an existing stylesheet that has its version at 1.0.

Comment: It's actually the processor that determines which version you can use, not the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "twist" here. Use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) and declare your key as:

```
<xsl:key name="file-by-root" match="file" use="substring-before(substring-after(dir, '/'), '/')" />
```